# React-Native App Crashes in Physical Android Device (When Dev Settings Pressed)

Tags: android, react-native, device

So I have a react-native app and it works fine in my simulat in computer, but when I want to check it in real device I get errors..

> 1.I run react-native run-android (app installs to real device, with just giving warning about adb reverse, cuz device's android version is
>   4.4.2)
>
> 2.When app opens in real device, says "Unable to load script from assets etc."
>
> 3.Then I try to open Dev Settings to connect to bundle via wifi as suggested and My app crashes!.. I tried in 2 different devices it
>   crashed in both.
>
> 4. I tracked it with android device monitor and I get some errors starting with :
>
>    07-18 17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):
>      android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error
>      inflating class android.widget.CheckBox 07-18 17:03:24.596:
>      E/AndroidRuntime(1160):   at
>      android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626) 07-18
>      17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at
>      com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
>      07-18 17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):   at
>      android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:675)
>      07-18 17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):   at
>      android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:700)
>      07-18 17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):   at
>      android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470) 07-18
>      17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at
>      android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 07-18
>      17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at
>      android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 07-18
>      17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at
>      android.preference.Preference.onCreateView(Preference.java:531) 07-18
>      17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at
>      android.preference.Preference.getView(Preference.java:494) 07-18
>      17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at
>      android.preference.PreferenceGroupAdapter.getView(PreferenceGroupAdapter.java:222)
>      07-18 17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):   at
>      android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2742) 07-18
>      17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at
>      android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1811) 07-18
>      17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at
>      android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:697) 07-18
>      17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at
>      android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:763) 07-18
>      17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at
>      android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1641) 07-18
>      17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at
>      android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2567) 07-18
>      17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at
>      android.view.View.layout(View.java:15819) 07-18 17:03:24.596:
>      E/AndroidRuntime(1160):   at
>      android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884) 07-18 17:03:24.596:
>      E/AndroidRuntime(1160):   at
>      android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
>      07-18 17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):   at
>      android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
>      07-18 17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):   at
>      android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440) 07-18
>      17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at
>      android.view.View.layout(View.java:15819) 07-18 17:03:24.596:
>      E/AndroidRuntime(1160):   at
>      android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884) 07-18 17:03:24.596:
>      E/AndroidRuntime(1160):   at
>      android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
>      07-18 17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):   at
>      android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1666)
>      07-18 17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):   at
>      android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1442) 07-18
>      17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at
>      android.view.View.layout(View.java:15819) 07-18 17:03:24.596:
>      E/AndroidRuntime(1160):   at
>      android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884) 07-18 17:03:24.596:
>      E/AndroidRuntime(1160):   at
>      android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
>      07-18 17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):   at
>      android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
>      07-18 17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):   at
>      android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440) 07-18
>      17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at
>      android.view.View.layout(View.java:15819) 07-18 17:03:24.596:
>      E/AndroidRuntime(1160):   at
>      android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884) 07-18 17:03:24.596:
>      E/AndroidRuntime(1160):   at
>      android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453) 07-18
>      17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at
>      android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388) 07-18
>      17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at
>      android.view.View.layout(View.java:15819) 07-18 17:03:24.596:
>      E/AndroidRuntime(1160):   at
>      android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884) 07-18 17:03:24.596:
>      E/AndroidRuntime(1160):   at
>      android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
>      07-18 17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):   at
>      android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
>      07-18 17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):   at
>      android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440) 07-18
>      17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at
>      android.view.View.layout(View.java:15819) 07-18 17:03:24.596:
>      E/AndroidRuntime(1160):   at
>      android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884) 07-18 17:03:24.596:
>      E/AndroidRuntime(1160):   at
>      android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453) 07-18
>      17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at
>      android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388) 07-18
>      17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at
>      android.view.View.layout(View.java:15819) 07-18 17:03:24.596:
>      E/AndroidRuntime(1160):   at
>      android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4884) 07-18 17:03:24.596:
>      E/AndroidRuntime(1160):   at
>      android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2391) 07-18
>      17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at
>      android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2099)
>      07-18 17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):   at
>      android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1270) 07-18
>      17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at
>      android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6721)
>      07-18 17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):   at
>      android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:812)
>      07-18 17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):   at
>      android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:612) 07-18
>      17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at
>      android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:582) 07-18
>      17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at
>      android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:798)
>      07-18 17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):   at
>      android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 07-18
>      17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at
>      android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 07-18
>      17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at
>      android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 07-18 17:03:24.596:
>      E/AndroidRuntime(1160):   at
>      android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5641) 07-18
>      17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at
>      java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 07-18
>      17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):     at
>      java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 07-18 17:03:24.596:
>      E/AndroidRuntime(1160):   at
>      com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1288)
>      07-18 17:03:24.596: E/AndroidRuntime(1160):   at
>      com.android.internal.os.Zygote 07-18 17:03:24.656: A/libc(1215): Fatal
>      signal 13 (SIGPIPE) at 0x000004bf (code=0), thread 1215 (uptime)

Any ideas how I can solve this..?

app/android/app/build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gotl"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-track-player')
    compile project(':react-native-sound-player')
    compile project(':react-native-sound')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.3.0'
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}
```

Comment: What is the Android minimum version in your gradle?

Comment: Where I can check it? in build.gradle?

Comment: Yes in your build.gradle you should have : minSdkVersion

Comment: Strange but I dont have it.. I will show what I have in gradle.. I showed in top

Comment: This is the build.gradle (Project: NameOfYourProject), you should have a a build.gradle(Module:app)

Comment: Where its located? This build.gradle which I showed located in App\android\build.gradle

Comment: What is the "etc...etc...etc..."? In particular, are any of the classes mentioned there something you wrote? Or is it all Android libraries?

Comment: I couldnt copy those all errors, I wrote by my hand thats why I wrote etc.etc.. If you think its critical, I can add all errors?

Comment: It's in 'projectFolder/android/app/build.gradle'

Comment: So what do you think??

Comment: No solution for that guys? No idea?

Comment: No idea guys? ..

Comment: my minSdkVersion = 19 then also my app is getting crashed

Answer (score 0):

I want to share that I noticed it crashes in android 4.4.4 version, but its not crashing in 5.0 version.. So anyone have some idea about it?..